# XPages - dependant combobox goes empty when submitting

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a Custom Control that opens a popup to fill some workitem.

The project is a combobox that gives the values of 3 others fields ( origin, inquirer and reason )

The combobox intervention is based on the reason combobox.

All the values are populated properly but there's also some validation because all fields are required.

When hitting the button Submit, the validation is done but it's emptying the field Intervention.

I can't find why.  Any help please

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

<xe:dialog id="dlgNote">        
    <xe:this.title><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        if (sessionScope.lang == "fr") {
            "Note";
        } else {
            "Work Item";
        }
    }]]></xe:this.title>

    <xp:panel>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoDocument var="WorkItem" formName="WorkItem"
                action="editDocument" documentId="#{javascript:viewScope.UNID}"
                ignoreRequestParams="true" />
        </xp:this.data>

        <xp:inputText id="wi_ParentUNID1" value="#{WorkItem.wi_ParentUNID}"
            defaultValue="#{javascript:client.getDocument().getUniversalID();}"
            disabled="true" style="display:none" rendered="#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable()}">
        </xp:inputText>

        <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{WorkItem.wi_WeekNo}" disabled="true" style="display:none">
            <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                now = new Date();
                onejan = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
                week = Math.ceil( (((now - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7 );
                @Text(@Year(now)) + "-" + @Text(week);
            }]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
        </xp:inputText>

        <xp:inputText id="inputText1"
            value="#{WorkItem.wi_Province}" disabled="true" style="display:none"
            rendered="#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable()}">
        <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("cli_Province").getValue()}]]></xp:this.defaultValue></xp:inputText>
        <xp:inputText id="inputText3"
            value="#{WorkItem.brokercode}" disabled="true" style="display:none"
            rendered="#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable()}">
        <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("cli_BrokerID").getValue()}]]></xp:this.defaultValue></xp:inputText>
        <xe:formTable id="formTable2" labelWidth="200px" labelPosition="above" disableErrorSummary="true" disableRowError="true">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xe:formRow id="formRow15" xp:key="footer">
                    <xp:panel style="padding-top:8px;">
                        <xp:button value="Submit" id="button1">
                            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                var dtcrt:java.util.Date = @Created();
                                var dtnow:java.util.Date = new Date();
                                var isSameDay:boolean = (dtnow.getFullYear()==dtcrt.getFullYear() && dtnow.getMonth()==dtcrt.getMonth() &&
                                                         dtnow.getDate()==dtcrt.getDate());

                                // Show button with new document
                                if (viewScope.UNID == "") {
                                    return true;
                                // Show button for Administrator
                                } else if (database.queryAccessRoles(session.getEffectiveUserName()).contains('[Administration]')) {
                                    return true;
                                // Show button to allows edition the same day until midnight.
                                } else if (isSameDay) {
                                    return true;
                                // Otherwise hide button
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }]]></xp:this.rendered>
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete" save="true"
                                id="eventHandler3">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                    WorkItem.save();
                                    getComponent("dlgNote").hide();
                                }]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>

                        <xp:button value="Cancel" id="button2">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="true" save="false" id="eventHandler4">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                    requestScope.ButtonAction="";
                                    getComponent("dlgNote").hide();
                                }]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                    </xp:panel>
                </xe:formRow>
            </xp:this.facets>

            <xe:formColumn id="formColumn6">
                <xe:formRow id="formRow1">
                    <xp:div><xp:message id="msg01" for="wi_Date"></xp:message></xp:div>
                    <xp:inputText id="wi_Date" value="#{WorkItem.wi_Date}" style="height:19px; width:194px;"
                        required="true" disableClientSideValidation="true">
                        <xp:this.converter>
                            <xp:convertDateTime
                                pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss">
                            </xp:convertDateTime>
                        </xp:this.converter>
                        <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                            @If(@IsNewDoc(), @Now(), getComponent("wi_Date").getValue());
                        }]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
                        <xp:this.validators>
                            <xp:validateRequired
                                message="You must enter a value.">
                            </xp:validateRequired>
                        </xp:this.validators>
                    </xp:inputText>

                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:label id="label3" value="Date:" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;" xp:key="label"></xp:label>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                </xe:formRow>

                <xe:formRow id="formRow16">
                    <xp:div><xp:message id="msg02" for="wi_Project"></xp:message></xp:div>
                    <xp:comboBox id="wi_Project" style="font-size:9pt; height:19px; width:200px;"
                        value="#{WorkItem.wi_Project}" required="true" disableClientSideValidation="true">
                        <xp:this.validators>
                            <xp:validateRequired
                                message="You must select a value.">
                            </xp:validateRequired>
                        </xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Text("")}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                //var col = (sessionScope.lang == "fr" ? 3 : 4);
                                //@DbLookup(@DbName(),"VWL010","Project",col,"[FAILSILENT]");

                                /////////
                                    var col = (sessionScope.lang == "fr" ? 3 : 4);

                                ///////////////////////////////////////////

                                var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
                                if (doc.hasItem("wi_Date")) 
                                {

                                    var dt:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("wi_Date").elementAt(0);
                                //  return @Day(dt.getDateOnly());


                                     var y = @Text(@Year(dt.getDateOnly()));
                                     var m = @Text(@Month(dt.getDateOnly()));
                                     var d = @Text(@Day(dt.getDateOnly()));
                                     var WorkItemdt = y + @Left(00+m,2) + @Left(00+d,2);

                                    //return WorkItemdt;
                                    //cutoff date pour voir les nouvelles listes déroulantes

                                    if ((WorkItemdt) < "20190201")
                                    {
                                    //vieille
                                        return @DbLookup(@DbName(),"VWL010A","Project",col,"[FAILSILENT]");
                                    }
                                    else{
                                    //nouveau
                                        return @DbLookup(@DbName(),"VWL010","Project",col,"[FAILSILENT]");
                                    }   
                                }
                                else{
                                    //nouveau
                                    return @DbLookup(@DbName(),"VWL010","Project",col,"[FAILSILENT]");
                                }



                            }]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" disableValidators="true"></xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:comboBox>

                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:label id="label2" value="Project:" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;" xp:key="label"></xp:label>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                </xe:formRow>

                <xe:formRow id="formRow12">
                    <xp:div><xp:message id="msg03" for="wi_Inquirer"></xp:message></xp:div>
                    <xp:comboBox id="wi_Inquirer" style="font-size:9pt; height:19px; width:200px;"
                        value="#{WorkItem.wi_Inquirer}" required="true" disableClientSideValidation="true">
                        <xp:this.validators>
                            <xp:validateRequired
                                message="You must select a value.">
                            </xp:validateRequired>
                        </xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Text("")}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:

                            var col = (sessionScope.lang == "fr" ? 10 : 9);
                                //var strKey = getComponent("wi_Project").getSubmittedValue();
                                var strKey = getComponent("wi_Project").getValue();
                                if (strKey != null) {
                                    strKey.trim();                                      
                                }                               
                                var items = @DbLookup(@DbName(),"VWL010",strKey,col,"[FAILSILENT]");
                                if (items != null) {
                                    return items;
                                }
                            }]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                    </xp:comboBox>

                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:label id="label7" value="Inquirer:" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;" xp:key="label"></xp:label>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                </xe:formRow>

                <xe:formRow id="formRow2">
                    <xp:checkBox text="Linked broker"
                        id="chkLinkedBroker" value="#{WorkItem.linkedbroker}" checkedValue="yes" uncheckedValue="no">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" disableValidators="true"></xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:checkBox>
                </xe:formRow>
            </xe:formColumn>

            <xe:formColumn id="formColumn5">
                <xe:formRow id="formRow13">
                    <xp:div><xp:message id="msg04" for="wi_AgentName"></xp:message></xp:div>
                    <xp:inputText id="wi_AgentName" value="#{WorkItem.wi_AgentName}"
                        style="font-size:9pt; height:19px; width:194px;" required="true" disableClientSideValidation="true">
                        <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                            @If(@IsNewDoc(), @Name("[CN]", @UserName()), getComponent("wi_AgentName").getValue());
                        }]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
                        <xp:this.validators>
                            <xp:validateRequired
                                message="You must enter a value.">
                            </xp:validateRequired>
                        </xp:this.validators>
                    </xp:inputText>

                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:label id="label4" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;" value="Agent Name:" xp:key="label"></xp:label>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                </xe:formRow>

                <xe:formRow id="formRow21">
                    <xp:div><xp:message id="msg05" for="wi_Origin"></xp:message></xp:div>
                    <xp:comboBox id="wi_Origin" style="font-size:9pt; height:19px; width:200px;"
                        value="#{WorkItem.wi_Origin}" required="true" disableClientSideValidation="true">
                        <xp:this.validators>
                            <xp:validateRequired
                                message="You must select a value.">
                            </xp:validateRequired>
                        </xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Text("") }]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                            var col = (sessionScope.lang == "fr" ? 8 : 7);
                                //var strKey = getComponent("wi_Project").getSubmittedValue();
                                var strKey = getComponent("wi_Project").getValue();
                                if (strKey != null) {
                                    strKey.trim();                                      
                                }                               
                                var items = @DbLookup(@DbName(),"VWL010",strKey,col,"[FAILSILENT]");
                                if (items != null) {
                                    return items;
                                }}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                    </xp:comboBox>

                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:label id="label18" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;" value="Origin:" xp:key="label"></xp:label>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                </xe:formRow>

                <xe:formRow id="formRow4"><xp:this.facets>
<xp:label value="Reason" id="label8" xp:key="label"
    style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;">
</xp:label></xp:this.facets>
                <xp:div>
                    <xp:message id="message1" for="wi_Reason"></xp:message></xp:div>
                <xp:comboBox id="wi_Reason"
                    value="#{WorkItem.wi_Reason}"
                    style="font-size:9pt; height:19px; width:200px;" required="true"
                    disableClientSideValidation="true">
                    <xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:validateRequired
                            message="You must select a value.">
                        </xp:validateRequired>
                    </xp:this.validators>
                    <xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "";}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:selectItems>
                    <xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var col = (sessionScope.lang == "fr" ? 12 : 11);
                                //var strKey = getComponent("wi_Project").getSubmittedValue();
                                var strKey = getComponent("wi_Project").getValue();
                                if (strKey != null) {
                                    strKey.trim();                                      
                                }                               
                                var items = @DbLookup(@DbName(),"VWL010",strKey,col,"[FAILSILENT]");
                                if (items != null) {

                                    return items;
                                }}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:selectItems>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="wi_Intervention"
                        immediate="true">

                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:comboBox></xe:formRow>



                ////////////INTERVENTION////////////////////////////
                <xe:formRow id="formRow19">
                    <xp:div><xp:message id="msg06" for="wi_Intervention"></xp:message></xp:div>                     
                    <xp:comboBox id="wi_Intervention"
                        style="font-size:9pt; height:19px; width:200px;"
                        value="#{WorkItem.wi_Intervention}" required="true"
                        disableClientSideValidation="true">
                        <xp:this.validators>
                            <xp:validateRequired
                                message="You must select a value">
                            </xp:validateRequired>
                        </xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Text("")}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>

                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var col = (sessionScope.lang == "fr" ? 14 : 13);
var value = getComponent("wi_Reason").getSubmittedValue(); 

if (value != null) {
                var value = value.trim();       
                return @DbLookup(@DbName(),"VWL010",value,col);
                }
                else{
                };






                    }]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                    </xp:comboBox>

                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:label id="label6" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;" value="Intervention:" xp:key="label"></xp:label>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                </xe:formRow>

                <xe:formRow id="formRow3">
                    <xp:panel id="panelbroker">
                        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                            var strValue:String = getComponent("chkLinkedBroker").getValue();
                            getComponent("chkLinkedBroker").getValue()=="yes";
                        }]]>
                        </xp:this.rendered>
                        <xp:div><xp:message id="msg07" for="wi_brokercode"></xp:message></xp:div>                           
                        <xp:label id="label5" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;" value="Broker code:">
                            <xp:br />
                            <xp:inputText id="wi_brokercode"
                                value="#{WorkItem.brokercode}" style="width:100px;"
                                required="true" disableClientSideValidation="true">
                                <xp:this.validators>
                                    <xp:validateRequired
                                        message="Enter a number of max. six digits.">
                                    </xp:validateRequired>
                                    <xp:validateLength maximum="6"
                                        minimum="1" message="Enter a number of max. six digits.">
                                    </xp:validateLength>
                                </xp:this.validators>
                            </xp:inputText>
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:panel>
                </xe:formRow>
            </xe:formColumn>

            <xe:formRow id="formRow9">
                <xp:div><xp:message id="msg09" for="document_form_body"></xp:message></xp:div>
                <xp:inputTextarea value="#{WorkItem.wi_Comments}"
                    id="document_form_body"
                    style="width:464px; height:125px; font-size:9pt;" required="true"
                    disableClientSideValidation="true">
                    <xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:validateRequired
                            message="You must enter a comment.">
                        </xp:validateRequired>
                    </xp:this.validators>
                </xp:inputTextarea>

                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:label id="label1" value="Comments:" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:9pt;" xp:key="label"></xp:label>
                </xp:this.facets>
            </xe:formRow>
        </xe:formTable>
    </xp:panel>

    <xp:eventHandler event="onHide" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tabbedPanel1"></xp:eventHandler>
</xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Have you checked so that the select items have correct values in html?

Comment: i have a workitem form with fields that are the same name

Comment: plesse provide complete code that we can copy/paste into an xpage

Answer (score 0):

A probable cause is this line `var value = getComponent("wi_Reason").getSubmittedValue();` in the `wi_intervention` combo box.

`getSubmittedValue()` is only used for validators. If you're code is not in a conditional validator - it's not here - `submittedValue` will always be null. If you're code is in a control's property (e.g. `selectItems`) or a button, you will only ever need `getValue()`.

For more clarification on when to use `getSubmittedValue()` and `getValue()` and more, see this webinar https://youtu.be/t7j_MR5uzCA, on the 2016 recorded webinars tab here http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/recorded-xpages-webinars